# Python | Искажение картинки

Tags: python, изображения

В Adobe Photoshop можно исказить картинку, используя инструмент "Масштабрование в учётом содержимого".
Оригинал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать такую же картинку, используя python?

Comment: Эффект называется `aware scale`. В интернете есть алгоритм.

Comment: а что, поисковики вам не подсказали ничего по этому вопросу?